# Powershell write output of a program to a console live and pipe to a file

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I am running a fairly complex python script from a powershell script. I would like to both display the stdout and stderr streams of the .python script in the console in real time (ie as the .py script writes to them) and also write them to a file.

My current solution looks like this:

```
Do-PreliminaryStuff
log = & ".\myPyScript.py" -myArgument "\this\that\thingy.txt" 2>&1 $log
Write-Output $log
$log | Out-File "$logDir\pyScriptLog.log"
Do-RestOfScript
```

This has the problem that the text is only printed out after the .py script has finished, making it much harder to watch the progress of the .py script.

Is there a way to somehow ..sample.. the pipeline as object go through it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [Tee-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113417) cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Tee-Object` - it splits the pipeline into a filestream before continuing:

```
& ".\myPyScript.py" -myArgument "\this\that\thingy.txt" 2>&1 |Tee-Object -FilePath $log
```